# Assuming that actual implicit tree resolution is linear, can the algorithm together with TypeApply be expotential?

Tags: scala, implicit, unification

I am running into very unpredictable compiler behaviour when compiling a single, small test file against my project. It tests for the presence of implicit values of witness classes parameterized with a recursive type. Minor changes to the type parameter produce results varying from `OutOfMemoryError`, `StackOverflowError`, compiling under a second, compiling in half an hour, hang indefinitely (scalac doesn't exit over the course of a whole night), does not compile (I won't say 'though it should', but it certainly *could* - implicit declarations can be composed into a tree that, with correct type parameters, matches the searched implicit value).

The implicit definitions themselves are not numerous and are recursive in a *linear* fashion: for any input type, at most one definition can be unified with the result, which accepts an implicit witness for a type argument of the input type. Think of a `HList`, but with varying 'link' subtypes, and searching for prefixes of an input `HList` type which meet certain criteria. I suspect that the issue comes from three factors:

1. The implicit type is contravariant in its 'input' type parameter, meaning sometimes the correct definition is declared for the supertype of the actual input type.
2. Some types that occur during resolution (the 'input' type) are abstract types with upper bounds (think along the lines of `L[H, T] forSome { type L[H, T <: HList] <: H::T }`).
3. The implicit declarations themselves contain many type parameters, as the implicit type has several type parameters and more type members, and the 'input type' for which the implicit is sought, needs to be decomposed into a type constructor, its type parameters, the bounds for those type parameters.

One discovery I made, which pushed me a little farther and lead to the above hypothesis, was that substituting a non-recursive supportive implicit declaration from a generic one (which called for the compiler to perform type unification and decompose a higher type into its type constructor and type parameters) with individual, straightforward definitions for each 'link' type individually sped things up considerably for some input types. The change, for illustrative purposes only, as the original has a lot of in-project dependencies, was as follows:

```
    implicit def composition[L <: FromSome, R[O] <: Elem[O],
                             J[+A <: FromSome, B[O] <: Elem[O]] <:
                                (A Link B) { type LikeLink[+X <: FromSome, Y[O] <: Elem[O]] <: X J Y }]
        :LinkComposition[L, R, J] = ???
```

into

```
    implicit def compositionA[L <: FromSome, R[O] <: Elem[O]] :LinkComposition[L, R, LinkA] = ???
    implicit def compositionB[L <: FromSome, R[O] <: Elem[O]] :LinkComposition[L, R, LinkB] = ???
    ...
```

where

```
    trait LinkComposition[L <: FromSome, R[O] <: Elem[O], J[+A <: FromSome, B[O] <: R[O]] <: A Link B]
         extends Decomposition[L J R, L, FromSome]
    trait Decomposition[-Whole, Part <: Bound, Bound]
```

`Decomposition` here is a type class for `Whole` which is used by the implicit definitions working with `FromSome`/`Link` types to reduce the type parameter to its prefix (`Part` and `Bound` are 'output' types), as the compiler is unable by itself to instantiate type parameters `[F <: Link[L, R], L <: FromSome, R[O] <: Elem[O]]` for `F =:= L LinkA R`.
This change made some cases which compiled in about half an hour or went out of memory compile instantaneuosly, but yet more complex types still do not work.

I therefore wonder: does the algorithm for instantiating the type parameters of generic methods is expotential in nature and can I learn more about it or debug somehow? Because I am on the third day of fighting this problem by blind, random changes, guesswork and prayer and making little progress.

Comment: I guess [Infer](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Infer.scala) is responsible for inference of method parameters. Implicits are resolved in [Implicits](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Implicits.scala).